# Spring security : Access denied handler doesn't work (xml config + preauthorize annotation on controller method)

Tags: java, spring-security, authorization, access-denied

Access-denied-handler doesn't work. The spring configuration is splitted on many xml file

1. applicationContext-spring-security.xml

```
<http auto-config='false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
    <access-denied-handler error-page='/accessdenied.htm" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern='/editprocedure.htm" access="hasAuthority('CAPABILITY_ADD')"/>
</http>
```

the access-denied-handler works well for xml config (as `<intercept-url pattern="/addjob.htm" access="hasAuthority('JOB_ADD')"/>`), but it dosen't when i use Preauthorize annotation !

2. [app]-servlet.xml

```
...
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
...
```

3. Controller

```
....
    @RequestMapping(value="/adminarea.htm")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN_AREA')")
    protected ModelAndView referenceData() throws Exception
    {....}
....
```

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

After investigating i found a solution for my problem :

1. create Custom Access Denied Handler class annotated with @ControllerAdvice
2. the must important is to define the sort order for our annotated component with high priority (e.g. @Order(value = 1))

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just rethrow the exception. The handle method of AccessDeniedHandler will be called.

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


    /**
     * Si erreur de sécurité au niveau méthode il faut re throw pour aller dans le 
     * handle de AccessDeniedHandler
     *
     * @param e
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    void handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException e) {
        throw e;
    }


}
```